# How do I call a function handle with an vector rather than a list of arguments?

Tags: matlab, function, function-handle

I was wondering how to call a function handle with an vector of inputs - rather than the list of aguments.

So if I have a function handle which is defined: (I guess it will be clear that I am working on fitting functions here)

```
fitFunctionHandle = @(a1, wG1, x1,a2, wG2, x2, c, x)(FitGaussianFn(x, [a1, 0, wG1, x1]) +FitGaussianFn(x, [a2, 0, wG2, x2]) + c
```

And I have an vector of inputs to hand to it

```
a1Init = 1
wG1Init = 2
x1Init = 3
a2Init = 4
wG2Init = 5
x2Init = 6
a2Init = 7
x = 8
%startPoint = [a1Init, wG1, x1,a2, wG2, x2, c]
inputArray = [a1Init, wG1, x1,a2, wG2, x2, c, x]
```

How do I call it with the vector startPoint as the input.  If I try (for example)

```
>> fitFunctionHandle(inputArray)
```

I get an error:

> Not enough input arguments.

That makes sense since it is expecting 8 inputs rather than a 8 element vector - but I'm wondering whether there is a way of calling it like that.  I think for example in python you can convert an array to a list or something.

I'm aware that I could simplify things in this example case where I have a list of known inputs so I could just do:

```
fitFunctionHandle(a1Init, wG1, x1,a2, wG2, x2, c, x)
```

or

```
fitFunctionHandle(inputArray(1),inputArray(2),inputArray(3,inputArray(4), inputArray(5), inputArray(6),inputArray(7),inputArray(8))
```

BUT! I guess I'm trying to allow for expansion where I don't know how many arguments there would be.
For bonus points (again since I'm working on fitting functions) - It would be cool to know how to call it when x is a vector as well.  I suspect that I would be doing something like

```
arrayfunc(fitFunctionHandle([startPoint,x]), xVector)
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the [`varargin`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/varargin.html), the general idea was already presented in [UnbearableLightness' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58954811/11089932). I just wanted to address your specific case.

It seems, you want to have some dynamic linear combinations of your `FitGaussianFn` calls with varying parameters, resulting in some complex function handle. For variable amount of terms, I would recommend to write a separate function to generate the final function handle. I made up a small toy example.

That's my `fitFunctionHandle.m` function:

```matlab
function h = fitFunctionHandle(varargin)

  n = numel(varargin);

  if (n < 2)
    error('Not enough input arguments.');
  end

  % Last input argument is considered t
  t = varargin{end};

  h = @(x) 0;
  for iArg = 1:n-1
    a = varargin{iArg}(1);
    b = varargin{iArg}(2);
    h = @(x) h(x) + (a*sin(b*x+t)); 
  end

end
```

Each input argument consists of two parameters, that form a `sin` term. An additional shift parameter `t` is always passed at last.

And, here's some test script:

```matlab
% Set up parameters
a1 = 1; b1 = 1;
a2 = 2; b2 = 2;
a3 = 3; b3 = 3;
t = pi/16;

% Evaluation point
x = pi/4;

% Compare results with explicit function calls
h = fitFunctionHandle([a1, b1], t);
res = h(x)
cmp = sin(x+t)

h = fitFunctionHandle([a1, b1], [a2, b2], t);
res = h(x)
cmp = sin(x+t) + 2*sin(2*x+t)

h = fitFunctionHandle([a1, b1], [a2, b2], [a3, b3], t);
res = h(x)
cmp = sin(x+t) + 2*sin(2*x+t) + 3*sin(3*x+t)
```

You see, it doesn't matter, how many parameter vectors are passed.

The output reveals, that the passed function handles are correct:

```
res =  0.83147
cmp =  0.83147
res =  2.7930
cmp =  2.7930
res =  4.4598
cmp =  4.4598
```

Regarding your last question, let's see this test:

```matlab
% Set up array of t parameters, and get set of function handles
t = [pi/16, pi/8, pi/4];
hh = arrayfun(@(x) fitFunctionHandle([a1, b1], x), t, 'UniformOutput', false);

% Compare results with explicit function calls
for iH = 1:numel(hh)
  h = hh{iH};
  res = h(x)
  cmp = sin(x + t(iH))
end
```

Here, the `t`, which is used for all `sin` terms in `fitFunctionHanle`, is a vector. The `arrayfun` call will return a cell array of function handles. Again, the output shows comparable results:

```
res =  0.83147
cmp =  0.83147
res =  0.92388
cmp =  0.92388
res =  1
cmp =  1
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a way to pass a variable number of input arguments to an anonymous function. 
Take a look at this example:

```
anonymousFunction = @(varargin)(image(varargin{:}));

x = [5 8];
y = [3 6];
C = [0 2 4 6; 8 10 12 14; 16 18 20 22];

input = {C};
anonymousFunction(input{:});

input = {x,y,C};
anonymousFunction(input{:});
```

You can see in the example that a variable number of inputs is used for calling the anonymous function. Of course, this depends on the actual function that is using the arguments (in this case, [image](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/image.html))